# Quadratically constrained quadratic programming in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Is there a function in R that does optimization with quadratic constraints?

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program

Comment: Please let me know if you come across specifically some  functions that allow some form of quadratic constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You should look through your options at the [CRAN Optimization and Mathematical ProgrammingTask View.](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/views/Optimization.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several software packages that can solve QCQPs.

CLSOCP solves SOCP problems.
DWD also solves SOCP problems.
Rcsdp solves SDP problems.

Keep in mind that

QCQPs are a subset of SOCPs, which in turn are a subset of SDPs.

There are references online illustrating how to formulate a QCQP as an [SOCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming#Example%3a_Quadratic_constraint) or [SDP](http://ece.tamu.edu/~cui/ECEN629/lecture4.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference.

There is a new package ECOSolveR to solve SOCPs

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try package quadprog: Functions to solve Quadratic Programming Problems.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/index.html

Comment: I think they only handle linear constraints with quadratic objective functions

Answer (score 0):

All these answer seem to forget one important thing: the solver to use depends heavily on whether the constraint is convex or not. If convex we can use readily available QCP / SOCP solvers (including Cplex and Gurobi). If not convex, we can try a general purpose NLP solver (such as IPOPT). Non-convex global solvers are another possibility, but most are not directly available under R.